# Extraer el valor de una clase enum

Tags: java, enum

Intento sacar el valor de una clase enum.

Al pedir por consola un número entero, el código seriía algo parecido a esto:

```
//metodo class
public enum TipoDeMadera {

    ROBLE,CAOBA;
}

//metodo main

System.out.println("introduzca un numero para elegir madera, 1 para roble, 2 para caoba");
int numero = Scanner entrada.nextInt();
```

¿Cómo podría mostrar en consola la madera elegida?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Los `enum` contienen el método `values()` el cual retorna un arreglo con los `enum`, en este caso `{ROBLE, CAOBA}` donde ROBLE esta en la posición cero (0) y CAOBA en la posición uno (1). Para su ejercición la salida sería

```
System.out.println(TipoDeMadera.values()[numero - 1]);
```